# Why isn't this .pyx file being recognized as a module?

Tags: python-3.x, cython, python-import, setuptools

I'm having trouble with relative imports, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong in this case. It *seems* like a straightforward relative import from another module in the same package, so I'm at a loss for how to debug this.

My project is set up like so:

```
.
├── ckmeans
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── _ckmeans.pxd
│   ├── _ckmeans_wrapper.pyx
│   ├── _ckmeans.py
│   ├── _evaluation.py
│   └── _utils.py
└── setup.py
```

At the top of `__init__.py`:

```
from ._ckmeans import ckmeans  # _ckmeans.py
```

And at the top of `_ckmeans.py`:

```
from . import _ckmeans_wrapper  # _ckmeans_wrapper.pyx
```

And at the top of `_ckmeans_wrapper.pyx`:

```
cimport _ckmeans  # _ckmeans.pxd
```

I run `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade -e .`, and everything seems to go smoothly. Then when I try to run my test suite, or `import ckmeans` in the interpreter, I get the error:

`ImportError: cannot import name '_ckmeans_wrapper'`

When I comment out the import statement from `__init__.py` and then `import ckmeans` in the interpreter, it does indeed seem to be missing the `_ckmeans_wrapper` module. I suspect that something is failing silently in the Cython build, but I don't have any idea how to debug.

Here's the `setup.py`:

```
import numpy as np
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import setup, Extension

extension = Extension(
    name='_ckmeans_wrapper',
    sources=['ckmeans/_ckmeans_wrapper.pyx'],
    language="c++",
    include_dirs=[np.get_include()]
)

setup(
    name='ckmeans',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=['ckmeans'],
    ext_modules = cythonize(extension),
    install_requires=['numpy', 'Cython']
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` argument to `Extension` was incorrect. It should be `name='ckmeans._ckmeans_wrapper'`.

Comment: It is possible to mark your own answer as the answer for the question that will then not be shown as unanswered in the list of questions.